# Is asking a question related to 'whitehat vs blackhat' a valid security question?

Tags: discussion

I see this: [Is asking a question about the legality and ethics of hacking back out of scope for this forum?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/is-asking-a-question-about-the-legality-and-ethics-of-hacking-back-out-of-scope).

But my question is going to be more opinion based in regards to the PRO's & CON's of both worlds directly related to the financial return vs the risk, etc...

Would this be a valid question or would it be too broad/opinion based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not, and here's why:

- **Opinion based** - that's a nono
- **Financial return vs risks** - again, that's opinion

Comment: One could argue that Financial return vs risk is something that is objective and therefore valid, although because I am so far from removed on being a expert on financial risks I would personally flag it to be sent off to http://quant.stackexchange.com/